# Open() is used for creating a file and opening a existing file.Could someone tell the difference?

Tags: c++, file

I have created a file name c.txt with open() and if I want to make changes in the file then I am going to open with open() then what is the difference? 
Could someone please help me out.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("c.txt");

    myfile << "gm all";
    myfile.close();
}
```

Comment: Your question is borderline-unclear, but I *think* you're asking how you *edit* an existing file using iostreams in C++.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a new program which opens the file for reading *and* writing (instead of writing-only like you do with the code you show)?

Comment: @WhozCraig I think the question is "open creates a file, unless the file already exists. why are they the same operation if the behavior is different?"

Comment: `ofstream.open(...)` actually invokes [`std::fopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen) with *write mode* (by default). As you can see in the table, it creates a new file if the file does not exist. If the file exists, then it destroys the content.

Comment: Otherwise, the semantics of "open a file for writing" has almost always meant "open the file for writing if it exist, truncating the contents. And if it doesn't exist create the file first". This semantics go back many decades, before C++ was even invented.

Comment: `what is the difference?` - In the first case the file does not exists, is created and is opened. In the second case the file exists, is not created and is opened.

Comment: In both cases you end up with an open empty file.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple!

ofstream: Output stream.
ifstream: Input stream.

Create the file with ofstream, and open it with ifstream.